# how to improve my text_search from database with 2000+ records

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Is there any way to improve my search bar to search faster from datagrid? I have a huge amount of data from my database, so when I search, typing from my search bar is somewhat laggy

```
Private Sub txt_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_search.TextChanged
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select * from tblchecklist where check_name like '%" & txt_search.Text & "%' or check_memo like '%" & txt_search.Text & "%' or check_num like '%" & txt_search.Text & "&' or check_amount like '%" & txt_search.Text & "%'", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ID"), dr.Item("storecode"), dr.Item("check_date"), dr.Item("check_num"), dr.Item("check_name"), dr.Item("check_memo"), dr.Item("check_amount"), dr.Item("check_group"), dr.Item("date_deposit"), dr.Item("date_release"), dr.Item("status"))
        End While
        dr.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't search on every change. If the user is entering multiple characters, there's no point searching multiple times. Start or restart a Timer, then search when that Timer Ticks. An Interval of 300-500 should prevent unnecessary searches while not making the user wait too long.

Comment: Also, you might also consider retrieving all the data to begin with and binding it via a BindingSource, then filtering locally. That way, you're not hitting the database over and over.

Comment: Even as it is, you could speed things up by populating a DataTable with the query results and then binding that to the grid. Adding the rows one by one is going to be slower.

Comment: Also, why are you executing the query on the UI thread? Why aren't you parameterizing your query and leaving yourself open to sql injection? Why aren't you using `Using` blocks for the MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, and the MySqlDataReader? Why are you using MsgBox and not MessageBox.Show?

Comment: Suggest: When using example code from Microsoft help (especially there) and other places to read the help pages on the methods used and 1) property allocate/dispose of them, 2) add proper error handling and 3) split your code into a database query method and a user interface event handler function.   Primary help sources, Microsoft, should include error handling and object cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Like JMcIlhinney pointed out, you're searching anytime the text changes whereas you probably don't want it to query right away. You can setup a technique called "debouncing" whereby you stop then start a timer when the TextChanged event fires and then execute the actual query in the Timer's Tick event.

Here is an example of doing just that:

```vb
Private WithEvents TimerDebounce As New Timer()

Private Sub MyForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TimerDebounce.Interval = 600 ' 600ms
End Sub

Private Sub TimerDebounce_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerDebounce.Tick
    ' do query
End Sub

Private Sub txt_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_search.TextChanged
    TimerDebounce.Stop()
    TimerDebounce.Start()
End Sub
```

Another suggestion was to preload the data and the filter the data locally via a BindingSource. What you could do is load the data into a DataTable when your form loads, bind the DataSource to the DataTable, then bind the DataGridView to the BindingSource, and then either filter or clear the filter in the debounce:

```vb
Private WithEvents TimerDebounce As New Timer()
Private BindingSourceChecklist As New BindingSource()
Private DataTableChecklist As DataTable()

Private Sub MyForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TimerDebounce.Interval = 600 ' 600ms
    DataTableChecklist = FetchData()
    BindingSourceChecklist.DataSource = DataTableChecklist
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSourceChecklist
End Sub

Private Sub TimerDebounce_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerDebounce.Tick
    Dim term = txt_search.Text
    BindingSourceChecklist.Filter = $"check_name LIKE '*{term}*'"
End Sub

Private Sub txt_search_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_search.TextChanged
    TimerDebounce.Stop()

    Dim term = txt_search.Text
    If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(term)) Then
        BindingSourceChecklist.ClearFilter()
    Else
        TimerDebounce.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FetchData() As DataTable
    Dim dataTable As New DataTable()
    Using command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblchecklist;", connection)
        Using adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(command)
            adapter.Fill(dataTable)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return dataTable
End Sub
```